# Break line in Ionic 3

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I would like it when it arrives at the bottom of the screen, it will break the line and continue below, full text: Transfer to Renovation Fund: # 3 Bonus Indication of user: lucasteste03

[image]

**CODE**

```
            <div  *ngIf="dado.currency_code == 'LTC'">

                <ion-row >
                    <ion-col col col-7>

                        <P style="font-size: 13px;">{{dado.created_at}}</P>
                        <p style="font-size: 13px;">{{dado.description}}</p>
                    </ion-col>
                    <ion-col col col-5>
                        <P style="font-size: 17px;color: #ff6a00;text-align: center">Ł {{dado.value}}</P>

                    </ion-col>

                </ion-row>

            </div>
        </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `text-wrap`:

```
<ion-col col col-7 text-wrap>
     <P text-wrap style="font-size: 13px;">{{dado.created_at}}</P>
     <p text-wrap style="font-size: 13px;">{{dado.description}}</p>
</ion-col>
```

Comment: @LucasZimmermann you can mark this as the answer if it solved your question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that will solve your problem:

```
<P class="item-text-wrap">{{dado.created_at}}</P>
```

Comment: not work...  <p class="item-text-wrap"  style="font-size: 13px;">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>

Answer (score 0):

```
<p text-wrap>{{dado.created_at}}</p>
```

`text-wrap` this works for me in ionic 5